# How to change image with just HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

I can only change the pictures using HTML and CSS. Clicking on the middle image, I want to see her big form, click the picture on right and see her big picture.

[image: This image]

Comment: your image link is not working and please include more information. I think your question is very unclear.

Comment: # Your link is `403 forbidden`, can you create a _reduced test case_? You posted a link to: https://i.hizliresim.com/JZXVbJ.png You need to use an "[online code editor](https://superdevresources.com/online-code-editors/)" to share your code snippet. If you create a "[reduced test case](https://css-tricks.com/reduced-test-cases/)", you'll be able to get useful intervention from the StackOverflow community. Why not try recreating your issue on an online code editor, like Codepen? Here's a signup form: https://codepen.io/accounts/signup/user/free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [CheckBox](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/) Hack for that.
When the checkbox is clicked, you increase the height and width of the image

Answer (score 3):

you can use image size:
`img.resize {
    width:500px; /* you can use % */
    height:500px;
}`
and for selected image you can use this link:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1):

**You can use element.active of Css**

```
img:active {
    width:200px;
    height:220px;
}
```